# Update Marker icon on zoom change in Jetpack Compose Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, maps

I had a logic in XML View Google maps where I was using custom clustering. I disabled `shouldRenderAsCluster` as `false` and called Cluster Manager on zoom change. Let's say only once if it's < 11f and only once if >= 11f.
Now in Compose Google Maps, I don't know how to update, even getting my current location and animating the camera makes it lag like hell. I've 500+ markers in debug and over 2k+ in prod falvor.

Things I've tried:

- Updating the mutableIntState(R.drawable.my_marker) and using it to update marker icon
- Using conditions inside and outside Google maps compose scope as well
- Launched effect on different scenarios
- Delay using coroutines
- Debounce

This is the function that should be called in viewModel

```
val zoomThreshold = 11f
var isBelowThreshold = false
var isAboveThreshold = false


fun checkForMarkerDrawableUpdate(zoomLevel: Float) {
        Timber.d("Called ViewModel")
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            if (zoomLevel < zoomThreshold && isBelowThreshold.not()) {
                isBelowThreshold = true
                isAboveThreshold = false
                Timber.d("Called If Case and drawable is dot marker")
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    _markerToRender.value = R.drawable.small_marker
                }
            } else if (zoomLevel >= zoomThreshold && isAboveThreshold.not()) {
                isBelowThreshold = false
                isAboveThreshold = true
                Timber.d("Called Else Case and drawable is drop marker")
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    _markerToRender.value = R.drawable.large_marker
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't even use the custom fab to navigate and animate to my current location, it recomposed **3 times**.

Overall, using LauncedEffect and Delay caused to log `Timber.d("Called ViewModel")` **several times**
I'm so confused at this moment, any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**TLDR**;
I want to refresh/update marker icons and data on a zoom level basis once it crosses or drops at a constant zoom level once one on the either cases. I've over 500+ markers on debug and 2K+ on prod flavour.

Things I've tried:

- Updating the mutableIntState(R.drawable.my_marker) and using it to update marker icon
- Using conditions inside and outside Google maps compose scope as well
- Launched effect on different scenarios
- Delay using coroutines
- Debounce

I'm expecting to get some leads so that I can myself get on the right track to understand the issue better and try resolving it.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will help out or not but check this out once. This might provide some necessary insights that you are looking for: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/google/maps/android/compose/MapClusteringActivity.kt

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. But I've already checked this out.